# Which Angular 2,4 or 5 Chart or Graph Modules Are The Best To Represent Chart Data

Tags: angular, graph, charts

Im looking for a great Chart Module for Angular 2, 4 or 5 thats works very well.
Im currently using ng2-charts and its not that great for me. 
I need something more customization in terms of the look and feel and the chart itself.

Any chart module is highly welcomed except ng2-charts or if anyone knows how to customize it per my requirements above.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I've used ng2-charts quite a bit, and the look and feel is pretty set, but you can customize them in just about any way that you can customize chart.js. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/ See those docs for more info

Answer (score 1):

Check out [CanvasJS Angular Charts](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/integration/angular/) - it has more customization options to change look & feel as per your requirements & has tons of examples with sample code in their [gallery](https://canvasjs.com/angular-charts/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend ECharts. Their Angular library is ngx-echarts (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts). The charts look beautiful and very easy to set up. Much easier than any other library out there. You just define the chartOption as EChartOptions in your typescript class, then use it anywhere within the class by referring to this.chartOption. Works well with APIs.